# Error while running perl inside of php

Tags: php, exec

I am trying to run a simple perl script inside of php. I keep getting these weird shell errors that i can't figure out why, below is the php code:

```
<?php
system("perl -e use Socket;\$i='192.168.1.1';\$p=443;print \$i;print \$p");
?>
```

Error I keep getting when running it:

```
syntax error at -e line 1, at EOF
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
sh: 1: =192.168.1.1: not found
sh: 1: =443: not found
```

I am running the php script through cli like this:

```
php script.php
```

Comment: Just run the command `perl -e use Socket;\$i='192.168.1.1';\$p=443;print \$i;print \$p` on your command line and you'll see what the problem is.

Comment: @mob, You mean `perl -e use Socket;$i='192.168.1.1';$p=443;print $i;print $p`

Comment: You're right, I deleted my comment :)

Answer (score 2):

```
"perl -e use Socket;\$i='192.168.1.1';\$p=443;print \$i;print \$p"
```

produces the string

```
perl -e use Socket;$i='192.168.1.1';$p=443;print $i;print $p
```

That's oh-so-wrong. That shell command is equivalent to the following five shell commands (assuming env vars `i` and `p` aren't set):

```
perl -e use Socket
='192.168.1.1'
=443
print
print
```

---

The Perl program you want to execute is

```
use Socket; $i='192.168.1.1'; $p=443; print $i; print $p;
```

or

```
use Socket; $i="192.168.1.1"; $p=443; print $i; print $p;
```

So the shell command you want to execute is

```
perl -e'use Socket; $i="192.168.1.1"; $p=443; print $i; print $p;'
```

or

```
perl -MSocket -e'$i="192.168.1.1"; $p=443; print $i; print $p;'
```

so the PHP command you want to execute is

```
system("perl -MSocket -e'\$i=\"192.168.1.1\"; \$p=443; print \$i; print \$p;'")
```